# Cross Entropy Loss for Semantic Segmentation Keras

Tags: image-processing, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I'm pretty sure this is a silly question but I can't find it anywhere else so I'm going to ask it here.

I'm doing semantic image segmentation using a cnn (unet) in keras with 7 labels. So my label for each image is (7,n_rows,n_cols) using the theano backend. So across the 7 layers for each pixel, it's one-hot encoded. In this case, is the correct error function to use categorical cross-entropy? It seems that way to me but the network seems to learn better with binary cross-entropy loss. Can someone shed some light on why that would be and what the principled objective is?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Binary cross-entropy loss should be used with `sigmod` activation in the last layer and it severely penalizes opposite predictions. It does not take into account that the output is a one-hot coded and the sum of the predictions should be 1. But as mis-predictions are severely penalizing the model somewhat learns to classify properly.

Now to enforce the prior of one-hot code is to use `softmax` activation with categorical cross-entropy. This is what you should use.

Now the problem is using the `softmax` in your case as Keras don't support softmax on each pixel.

The easiest way to go about it is permute the dimensions to (n_rows,n_cols,7) using `Permute` layer and then reshape it to (n_rows*n_cols,7) using `Reshape` layer. Then you can added the `softmax` activation layer and use crossentopy loss. The data should also be reshaped accordingly.

The other way of doing so will be to implement depth-softmax :

```
def depth_softmax(matrix):
    sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + K.exp(-x))
    sigmoided_matrix = sigmoid(matrix)
    softmax_matrix = sigmoided_matrix / K.sum(sigmoided_matrix, axis=0)
    return softmax_matrix
```

and use it as a lambda layer:

```
model.add(Deconvolution2D(7, 1, 1, border_mode='same', output_shape=(7,n_rows,n_cols)))
model.add(Permute(2,3,1))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Lambda(depth_softmax))
```

If `tf` `image_dim_ordering` is used then you can do way with the `Permute` layers.

For more reference check [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1169).

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer! I went with the reshape, softmax and categorical cross-entropy. Would you expect there are any substantial performance differences between the two methods in terms of speed or final accuracy? Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't worked on this scenario myself but you can check both of them. Also another thing that you can try is first create a model with final layer as `sigmoid` and binary cross-entropy loss and once training is done replace the top  layer and and end with `softmax` and retrain with  categorical cross-entropy. The 2nd training will converge quickly but I would bet overall the training time will reduce and will have better accuracy.

Comment: Hi indraforyou, I am also working on a semantic segmentation case. The masked image is represented as (1,n_rows, n_cols). For this case, can I use sigmoid and binary cross-entrophy? Are there any specific procedures to be included?

Comment: @user297850 for single channel you don't need to do anything special. You can simply use sigmoid and binary cross-entrophy.

Comment: @indraforyou I am kind of confused by your function. `axis=0` means that you take the sum along the rows? I would assume that it would be `axis=-1` as you want to sum along the depth (however, substituting `axis=0` for `axis=1` does not work, it will throw an error). Also, does this really result in the softmax? I would assume it to be `lambda x: K.exp(x)` instead...

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution of @indraforyou and think that the proposed method has some mistakes. As the commentsection does not allow for proper code segments, here is what I think would be the fixed version:

```
def depth_softmax(matrix):

    from keras import backend as K

    exp_matrix = K.exp(matrix)
    softmax_matrix = exp_matrix / K.expand_dims(K.sum(exp_matrix, axis=-1), axis=-1)
    return softmax_matrix
```

This method will expect the ordering of the matrix to be (height, width, channels).