# U-Net with Pixel-wise weighted cross entropy: Input dimension errors

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have been using [Zhixuhao's implementation of U-Net](https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet) to try to do semantic binary segmentation and I modified it slightly using suggestions from this Stackoverflow answer: 
[Keras, binary segmentation, add weight to loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555820/keras-binary-segmentation-add-weight-to-loss-function/48577360#48577360)
to be able to do a pixel-wise weighted binary cross-entropy, as they do in the original U-Net paper ([see page 5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.04597.pdf)), to force my U-Net to learn border pixels. Essentially the idea is to add a lambda layer that computes the pixel-wise weighted cross-entropy within the model itself and then use an "identity loss" that just copies the output of the network.

Here is what my input data looks like:
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76QWm.png) [groundtruth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQv1e.png) [weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMHxW.png)

And here is what my code looks like:

```
def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):

    inputs = Input(input_size)
    # [... Unet architecture from Zhixuhao's model.py file...]
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid', name='true_output')(conv9)

    mask_weights = Input(input_size)
    true_masks = Input(input_size)
    loss1 = Lambda(weighted_binary_loss, output_shape=input_size, name='loss_output')([conv10, mask_weights, true_masks])

    model = Model(inputs = [inputs, mask_weights, true_masks], outputs = loss1)
    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss =identity_loss)
```

And added those two functions:

```
def weighted_binary_loss(X):
    y_pred, weights, y_true = X
    loss = keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)
    loss = multiply([loss, weights])
    return loss

def identity_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred
```

And finally here is the relevant part of my main.py:

```
input_size = (256,256,1)
target_size = (256,256)
myGene = trainGenerator(5,'data/moma/train','img','seg','wei',data_gen_args,save_to_dir=None,target_size=target_size)
model = unet(input_size=input_size)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_moma_weights.hdf5',monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=300,epochs=5,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

Now this code runs fine, I can train my U-Net and it does learn border pixels, but *only* if I resize my input images to be 256*256 in size. If I instead use input_size=(256,32,1) and target_size=(256,32) in main.py , which is the relevant dimensions for my data and that allows me to use bigger batch sizes, I get the following error:

> ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (256,
>   32, 1) (256, 32)

For the line `loss = multiply([loss, weights])`. And indeed the weights have one extra singleton dimension. I don't understand why the error is not raised when I use 256*256 inputs, but I tried to make both inputs the same dimensions with either k.expand_dims() or Reshape(), but while the code does not issue an error and the loss converges, when I test my network on extra inputs I get blank outputs (ie fully grey or white or black images, or stuff that has nothing to do with my inputs).

So this is a lot of text for the following question: Why does multiply() issue an error in the 256*32 case and not 256*256, and why creating/removing dimensions on the inputs does not help?

Thanks!

ps: In order to get the network to output the actual prediction instead of the pixel-wise loss after training, I remove the loss layer and the two extra input layers with the following code:

```
new_model = Model(inputs=model.inputs,outputs=model.get_layer("true_output").output)
new_model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy')
new_model.set_weights(model.get_weights())
```

This works fine (again in the 256*256 case at least)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone who stumbles upon this question, here is how I implemented the loss function:

```
def pixelwise_weighted_binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    '''
    Pixel-wise weighted binary cross-entropy loss.
    The code is adapted from the Keras TF backend.
    (see their github)
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    y_true : Tensor
        Stack of groundtruth segmentation masks + weight maps.
    y_pred : Tensor
        Predicted segmentation masks.

    Returns
    -------
    Tensor
        Pixel-wise weight binary cross-entropy between inputs.

    '''
    
    try:
        # The weights are passed as part of the y_true tensor:
        [seg, weight] = tf.unstack(y_true, 2, axis=-1)

        seg = tf.expand_dims(seg, -1)
        weight = tf.expand_dims(weight, -1)
    except:
        pass

    epsilon = tf.convert_to_tensor(K.epsilon(), y_pred.dtype.base_dtype)
    y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, epsilon, 1. - epsilon)
    y_pred = tf.math.log(y_pred / (1 - y_pred))

    zeros = array_ops.zeros_like(y_pred, dtype=y_pred.dtype)
    cond = (y_pred >= zeros)
    relu_logits = math_ops.select(cond, y_pred, zeros)
    neg_abs_logits = math_ops.select(cond, -y_pred, y_pred)
    entropy = math_ops.add(relu_logits - y_pred * seg, math_ops.log1p(math_ops.exp(neg_abs_logits)), name=None)
    
    # This is essentially the only part that is different from the Keras code:
    return K.mean(math_ops.multiply(weight, entropy), axis=-1)
```