# Keras gives 'Not JSON Serializable' error when saving the model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I'm implementing a fully convolutional neural network for image segmentation by using unet defined here

https://github.com/zhixuhao

To give different weights to the pixels of different classes I defined an extra Lambda layer, as suggested here

[Keras, binary segmentation, add weight to loss function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48555820/keras-binary-segmentation-add-weight-to-loss-function/48577360#48577360)

The problem is that Keras raises this error when saving the model

```
.....
self.model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
.....
TypeError: ('Not JSON Serializable:', b'\n\x15clip_by_value/Minimum\x12\x07Minimum\x1a\x12conv2d_23/Identity\x1a\x17clip_by_value/Minimum/y*\x07\n\x01T\x12\x020\x01')
```

My network is defined in an external function

```
def weighted_binary_loss(X):
    y_pred, y_true, weights = X
    loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    weights_mask = y_true*weights[0] + (1.-y_true)*weights[1]
    loss = multiply([loss, weights_mask])
    return loss    

def identity_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return y_pred


def net()
.....
....
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
w_loss = Lambda(weighted_binary_loss, output_shape=input_size, name='loss_output')([conv10, inputs, weights])
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = w_loss)
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-5), loss = identity_loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

that I call in my main function

```
...
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('temp_model.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
model.fit_generator(imgs,steps_per_epoch=20,epochs=1,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

When I erase the Lambda layer, the error desappears

```
...
conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-5), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I'm using 
Keras==2.2.4, tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0b1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are computing the loss in the layer of a model. It is not a good practice to accomodate the loss function as a layer. You can compute your weighted loss using custom loss function.

So your code can be rewritten as follows:

```
def weighted_binary_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    weights = [0.5, 0.6]  # Define your weights here
    loss = binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    weights_mask = y_true*weights[0] + (1.-y_true)*weights[1]
    loss = multiply([loss, weights_mask])
    return loss  

conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)
model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = conv10)
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-5), loss = weighted_binary_loss, metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

If it is needed that `weights` is a dynamic property and you have to send it as a separate parameter in loss function, you can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961428/make-a-custom-loss-function-in-keras).