# keras - per-pixel, unnormalized, softmax loss for semantic segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, semantic-segmentation

I'm troubleshooting a Keras/TensorFlow U-Net for semantic segmentation.  One thing I keep coming across are claims like this....

> "Now the problem is using the softmax in your case as Keras don't
>   support softmax on each pixel."

which is stated here (as well as lots of other places): [Cross Entropy Loss for Semantic Segmentation Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118821/cross-entropy-loss-for-semantic-segmentation-keras)

They typical solution is to unroll rows and cols into 1d so the output (4d) tensor of shape (batch, rows, cols, n_classes) becomes a 3d tensor (batch, rows*cols, n_classes) and apply dense softmax to that.

But this dummy example leads me to think that a Conv2d layer with 1x1 kernel and 'softmax' activation **DOES** perform per-pixel softmax.

Am I wrong?

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(345)

from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model 
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform
```

mimick input to per-pixel softmax classifier in this case a 3x3 field with 5 filters

```
np.random.seed(234)
dummy_input = np.random.random(45).astype('float32')
dummy_input = dummy_input.reshape((1,3,3,5))
```

build 2 networks with the same random weights (one linear, one softmax)

```
conv_input = Input(shape=(3,3,5,), dtype='float32')

pred_layer_softmax = Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1), kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=0., maxval=1.), 
                            padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', activation='softmax')(conv_input)

pred_layer_linear = Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=(1,1), strides=(1,1),
                           padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', activation='linear')(conv_input)
```

models

```
m_softmax = Model(conv_input, pred_layer_softmax)
m_linear = Model(conv_input, pred_layer_linear)

# keep weights the same for both networks
m_linear.set_weights(m_softmax.get_weights())
```

predictions

```
pred     = m_softmax.predict(dummy_input)
pred_lin = m_linear.predict(dummy_input)
```

Do the two networks make the same predictions?  yes.

```
print('\nsoftmax pred')
print(pred.argmax(axis=3))
print('\nlinear_pred')
print(pred_lin.argmax(axis=3))

softmax pred
[[[1 1 0]
  [1 1 0]
  [1 0 1]]]

linear_pred
[[[1 1 0]
  [1 1 0]
  [1 0 1]]]
```

Do the sum of per-pixel class probabilities add up to 1.0 for softmax?  Yes.

```
print('\nsoftmax - sum class probs')
print(pred.sum(axis=3))
print('\nlinear - sum class probs')
print(pred_lin.sum(axis=3))

softmax - sum class probs
[[[ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]
  [ 1.  1.  1.]]]

linear - sum class probs
[[[ 1.88952112  2.50639653  2.06084657]
  [ 1.81122136  2.21819067  2.01038122]
  [ 1.92753291  1.85993922  2.27295876]]]
```

What am I missing?  This looks like per-pixel softmax is working fine, right?

Is there some fundamental thing I'm not understanding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your loss?

Comment: honestly, my network doesn't converge right now, so I'm trying lots of things. 
 At the moment my loss function is Keras's sparse_categorical_crossentropy(from_logits=False).

Comment: also...  I think for 2 classes (background vs. foreground, which is the current task), binary_crossentropy on a sigmoid activation should work too...  but I'd like to keep it generalizable to more classes, hence my attempt at crossentropy on softmax instead.

Comment: What is the value of your `loss`?

Comment: on a 224x224 pixel prediction, loss starts ~ 5.0.

Comment: From my perspective - everything seems fine. You could try to overfit it on a small subset of data.